How to get upstream calling pipeline info in downstream pipeline without passing as parameter on Jenkins?
In Jenkins I have one pipeline triggering another pipeline through the use of "build job" syntax:
Inside the Upstream_Job.groovy
def build_result = build job: "Downstream_Job", parameters: [
    [$class: "StringParameterValue", name: "param1", value: var1],
    [$class: "StringParameterValue", name: "param2", value: var2],
]

I wish to obtain the name Upstream_Job info inside the Downstream_Job without explicitly passing as a parameter.
Setting in Upstream_Job.groovy
env.CURRENT_JOB_NAME = "Upstream_Job";
However I would get null when I try to print this env.CURRENT_JOB_NAME in the downstream job.
However, the scope of env in one job is typically not extended to the scope of another job.
Even though Jenkins' pipeline syntax doc says:
These definitions will also be available via the REST API during the build or after its completion, and from upstream Pipeline builds using the build step. for env.
It does not have to be set as env, as long as I can know the name Upstream_Job that invokes the Downstream_Job. It can be put in currentBuild if that can be retrieved by the Downstream_Job.

You can access build causes through the currentBuild variable:
script {
    print currentBuild.getBuildCauses('org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildUpstreamCause')[0]?.upstreamProject
}

getBuildCauses returns a filtered list of your build causes, which can be long if it's a timer triggering a job that is triggering another job, for example. In this case you are only interested in the first parent workflow.
The list can be empty if there are no workflows in your build causes, for example if you trigger it manually, so [0] would return null and we need a safe navigation ?. operator there.

I am able to successfully get the upstream pipeline name this way.
However, I did some manipulations so the upstream pipeline consists of some tiny jobs that each has an env.CURRENT_JOB_NAME
This env variable would be updated each time a job finishes and a new job is run.
I wonder if it is possible to get the environment variable of the upstream pipeline inside the downstream pipeline too without passing as parameters?

I wonder if we are using the word "job" in the same sense. In Jenkins jobs are what you run. It can be a FreeStyle job, a Pipeline job, or some other, more exotic types of jobs. But pipelines do not consist of jobs. They might have different stages.

We probably use in slightly different sense.
By pipeline above I was referring to pipeline job.
For "job" I use, can consider it as a Jenkins job stage.
Basically, I want to retrieve the environment variables in one downstream Jenkins pipeline job from one upstream Jenkins pipeline job.
Is there some way to obtain them without passing as parameters from the build job line?

There might be, but it makes your code brittle. Variable scoping is a good thing.
